# How to use fnServerData?

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

Can anyone show me how to use `fnServerData`?.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#example').dataTable( {
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "xhr.php",
    "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings ) {
      oSettings.jqXHR = $.ajax( {
        "dataType": 'json',
        "type": "POST",
        "url": sSource,
        "data": aoData,
        "success": fnCallback
      } );
    }
  } );
} );
```

Below is my Ajax call, i want to replace the `ajax call` with the fnServerData.

```
   $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        jsonp: true,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data.value, function(i,item){
                table.fnAddData(item);
            });
        },
        error: function (e) {
            console.log(e.message);
        }
    });
```

http://datatables.net/ref#fnServerData

What is sSource, fnCallback and oSettings?. Can anyone show me how to use `fnServerData`?.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

sSource, fnCallback and oSettings are generated by Datatables.

sSource is the url for your ajax call. When you initialize the datatable you specify this in sAjaxSource. So you should pass in your url var as sAjaxSource.

oSettings is created and maintained by datatables js. It stores important information about the state of your datatable. Detailed documentation available here:
https://datatables.net/docs/DataTables/1.9.0/DataTable.models.oSettings.html

I think however, your success function is unnecessary. You should specify aoColumns as an option during initialization and then datatables will populate the data for you.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
 $('#example').dataTable( {
   "aoColumns": [
       { "mData": "engine" },
       { "mData": "browser" },
       { "mData": "platform.inner" },
       { "mData": "platform.details.0" },
       { "mData": "platform.details.1" }
     ]
   }),
   "bProcessing": true,
   "bServerSide": true,
   "sAjaxSource": url,
   "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings ) {
     oSettings.jqXHR = $.ajax( {
       "dataType": 'json',
       "type": "POST",
       "url": sSource,
       "data": aoData,
       "success": fnCallback,
       "error": function (e) {
           console.log(e.message);
       }
     });
   }
 });
});
```

More information on aoColumns here: http://www.datatables.net/usage/columns
Also, have a looka the examples on the datatables page. There should be an example for anything you need:
http://www.datatables.net/usage/columns

Regards,
Saz

---

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send extra fields from the client to the server, you can add properties to `aoData` object like this:

```
"fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings) {
     aoData.push({ "name": "Input1", "value": "xx" });

     oSettings.jqXHR = $.ajax({
         "dataType": 'json',
         "type": "POST",
         "url": sSource,
         "data": aoData,
         "success": fnCallback
     });
},
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings ) {                               
    oSettings.jqXHR = $.post( sSource, aoData, function( data ) {               
        //alert(data.toSource());

        if ( ! parseInt(data.iTotalRecords) > 0 )
            alert('ZeroRecords');

        fnCallback(data);
        //fnCustomCallback(data);

    },'json');
}
```