# Serverside JQuery Datatable Results Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion, datatables

All,

I am using a great example of a serverside coldfusion jquery datatable I found at the following website. [Site Here](http://www.mccran.co.uk/index.cfm/2010/4/29/JQuery-Datatables-plugin-example-using-a-server-side-data-request-coldfusion)

In the example code, the table and select statments were exposed in the JS file and I needed to included more than one table in the search. The original code looked like this.

**ORIGINAL WORKING CODE**

```
"fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback ) {
    aoData.push(
        { "name": "table", "value": "ukLocationCodes" },
        { "name": "sql", "value": "SELECT [id], [varCode], [varLocation]" }
        );

        $.ajax( {"dataType": 'json',
             "type": "POST",
             "url": sSource,
             "data": aoData,
             "success": fnCallback} );
```

The original code had this for the query search on the ColdFusion page.

```
 <cfquery name="rResult" datasource="A8002CMS">
    #preservesinglequotes(form.sql)#
    FROM #form.table#

    WHERE 1 = 1
<cfif len(form.sSearch)>
        AND (
<cfloop from="1" to="#listLen(variables.fieldlist)#" index="variables.index">
#listGetAt(variables.fieldlist, variables.index,',')# LIKE '%#form.sSearch#%' <cfif variables.index LT listLen(variables.fieldlist)> OR </cfif>
</cfloop>
    )
</cfif>
<cfif isdefined('form.iSortCol_0')>
    ORDER BY
<cfloop from="0" to="#form.iSortingCols-1#" index="variables.i">
    #listGetAt(variables.fieldlist,form["iSortCol_#variables.i#"]+1)# #form["sSortDir_#variables.i#"]# 
    <cfif variables.i is not form.iSortingCols-1>, 
    </cfif>
</cfloop>
<!--- create the JSON response --->
<cfsavecontent variable="variables.sOutput"><cfoutput>{
    "sEcho": #form.sEcho#,
    "iTotalRecords": #qGetCount.fullCount#,
    "iTotalDisplayRecords": #rResult.recordcount#,
    "aaData": [ 
    <cfloop query="rResult" startrow="#form.iDisplayStart+1#" endrow="#form.iDisplayStart+form.iDisplayLength#"><cfset variables.count=variables.count+1>
[<cfloop list="#variables.fieldlist#" index="variables.i">
<!--- custom translations --->
"#rResult[variables.i][rResult.currentRow]#"
<cfif variables.i is not listLast(variables.fieldlist)>, </cfif>
</cfloop>]
```

**CHANGED CODE, WORKS FINE UNTIL YOU TYPE IN A SEARCH**

In order to lookup more than one table and hide the table and select, I changed the JS script to the following below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#displayData').dataTable( {
    "processing": true,
    "stateSave": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
    "url": "MyVolunteers.cfm",
    "type": "POST"
        },

    "columns": [ 
                    {"name": "EMPLOYEE_ID" , "className": "hidden"},
                    {"name": "EVER_NUM" , "className": "hidden" , "orderable": "true"},
                    {"name": "LAST_NAME", "title": "LAST NAME", "orderable": "true"},
                    {"name": "FIRST_NAME", "title": "FIRST NAME", "orderable": "true"},
                    {"name": "SortOrderDate", "title": "APP DATE", "orderable": "true"},
                    {"name": "DOCS_VER", "className": "hidden"},
                    {"name": "DOCS_WAIT", "title": "APP STATUS", "orderable": "true"},
                    {"name": "APP_STATUS", "title": "PROGRESS", "orderable": "true"},
                    {"name": "LOCATION_NAME", "title": "LOCATION", "orderable": "true"},
                    {"title": "OPTIONS", "orderable": "false"}
                ],

 "columnDefs": [

                {
                    <cfset E = "+row[0]+"/>
                    "render": function ( data, type, row )
                    {return "<a class='btn btn-primary btn-xs' href='candidate/?select="#E#"'>view</a> <a class='btn btn-success btn-xs' href='candidate/?select=#e_id#"+"'>edit</a>";},
                    "targets": -1
                },

                {

                    "render": function ( data, type, row )
                    {
                          var color = 'black';
                           if (row[5] == 1) {
                            color = 'green';
                            ColorCheck = 'VALIDATED';
                            IconChoice = ' fa fa-check-square-o';
                          } 
                          else if (row[6] == 1) {
                            color = 'orange';
                            ColorCheck = 'WAITING';
                            IconChoice = 'fa fa-spin fa-spinner';
                          } 
                          else  {
                            color = 'red';
                            ColorCheck = 'NON-VALID';
                            IconChoice = 'fa fa-exclamation-triangle';
                          }

                          return '<span style="color:' + color + '"><i class="' + IconChoice + '"></i> ' + ColorCheck + '</span>';
                        },
                        "targets": -4


                },
                {

                         "render": function ( data, type, row )
                         {
                          var appstat = 'black';
                           if (row[5] == 1) {
                            appstat = 'green';
                            TextStatus = 'FINISHED';
                            IconChoice = 'fa fa-check';
                          } 
                           else  {
                            appstat = 'black';
                            var TextStatus = row[7];
                            IconChoice = 'fa fa-chevron-right';
                          }
                          return '<span class="text-uppercase" style="color:' + appstat + '"><i class="' + IconChoice + '"></i> ' + TextStatus + '</span>';
                        },
                        "targets": -3
                },
                { "visible": false,  "targets": [ 0 ] }
        ],
"pagingType": "full_numbers",
"order": [[2,'asc']],
"language": {
        "lengthMenu": "Page length: _MENU_",
        "search": "Filter:",
        "zeroRecords": "No matching records found"
                                },
                                "data": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback ) {
        aoData.push(
            );

            $.ajax( {"dataType": 'json',
                 "type": "POST",
                 "url": sSource,
                 "data": aoData,
                 "success": fnCallback} );
                        }
                } );
            } );
setInterval( function () {
$('#displayData').DataTable().ajax.reload();
}, 30000 );
```

Changed the query to read like the following below.

```
<cfsilent>
<cfparam name="form.table" default="">
<cfparam name="form.columns" default="">
<cfparam name="form.editButtonText" default="">
<cfparam name="form.editButtonTarget" default="">
<cfparam name="form.search" default="">
<cfparam name="variables.fieldlist" default="">

<cfsetting showDebugOutput="true">
<cfsetting enablecfoutputonly="true">
<cfprocessingdirective suppresswhitespace="true">

<!--- this comes from the AJAX script in the template --->
<cfset variables.fieldlist=form.columns>
<cfset variables.count=0>

<!--- strip off the comma if it is the last element --->
<cfif right(variables.fieldlist,'1') EQ ",">
    <!--- last char is a comma --->
    <cfset variables.listLength = len(variables.fieldlist)>
    <cfset variables.fieldlist = left(variables.fieldlist, variables.listLength-1)>
</cfif>

<!--- get count of records --->
<cfquery name="qGetCount" datasource="MySQLDATABASE">
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS fullCount
    FROM VOLTABLE1
    WHERE ARCHIVE IS NULL
</cfquery>

<cfquery name="rResult" datasource="MySQLDATABASE">
    SELECT VOLTABLE1.EMPLOYEE_ID, VOLTABLE1.EVER_NUM, VOLTABLE1.LAST_NAME, VOLTABLE1.FIRST_NAME, VOLTABLE1.DOCS_VER, VOLTABLE1.DOCS_WAIT, VOLTABLE1.APP_STATUS, VOLTABLE1.LOCATION_ID, DATE_FORMAT(VOLTABLE1.EMPLOYEE_DATE,'%Y-%m-%d %r') AS SortOrderDate, VOLTABLE2.LOCATION_NAME
    FROM VOLTABLE1
    RIGHT JOIN
    VOLTABLE2
    ON VOLTABLE1.LOCATION_ID = VOLTABLE2.LOCATION_ID
    WHERE 1 = 1 AND VOLTABLE1.ARCHIVE IS NULL
<cfif len(form.search)>
        AND (
<cfloop from="1" to="#listLen(variables.fieldlist)#" index="variables.index">
#listGetAt(variables.fieldlist, variables.index,',')# LIKE '%#form.search#%' <cfif variables.index LT listLen(variables.fieldlist)> OR </cfif>
</cfloop>
    )
</cfif>
<cfif isdefined('form.iSortCol_0')>
    ORDER BY
<cfloop from="0" to="#form.iSortingCols-1#" index="variables.i">
    #listGetAt(variables.fieldlist,form["iSortCol_#variables.i#"]+1)# #form["sSortDir_#variables.i#"]# 
    <cfif variables.i is not form.iSortingCols-1>, 
    </cfif>
</cfloop>

</cfif>
</cfquery>

<!--- strip off the table name from the values, otherwise it will break making the json --->
<cfset variables.fieldlist = ReplaceNoCase(variables.fieldlist,'VOLTABLE1.','','all')>
<cfset variables.fieldlist = ReplaceNoCase(variables.fieldlist,'VOLTABLE2.','','all')>

<!--- This is where I think the error is happening, I've read the JQuery Datatable documentation and I still am unable to resolve the issue.--->
<cfsavecontent variable="variables.sOutput"><cfoutput>{
    "draw": #form.draw#,
    "recordsTotal": #qGetCount.fullCount#,
    "recordsFiltered": #rResult.recordcount#,
    "data": [ 
    <cfloop query="rResult" startrow="#form.iDisplayStart+1#" endrow="#form.iDisplayStart+form.iDisplayLength#"><cfset variables.count=variables.count+1>
[
<cfloop list="#variables.fieldlist#" index="variables.i">
<!--- custom translations --->
<cfset outputResults = ReplaceNoCase(rResult[variables.i][rResult.currentRow],'"','', 'ALL' ) />
"#outputResults#"
<cfif variables.i is not listLast(variables.fieldlist)>, </cfif>
</cfloop>
]

<cfif rResult.recordcount LT form.iDisplayStart+form.iDisplayLength>
    <cfif variables.count is not rResult.recordcount AND rResult.recordcount NEQ rResult.currentRow>,</cfif>
<cfelse>
    <cfif variables.count LT form.iDisplayLength>,</cfif>
</cfif>

</cfloop>
            ]
}</cfoutput></cfsavecontent>
</cfprocessingdirective>
</cfsilent>
<cfoutput>#variables.sOutput#</cfoutput>
```

The data shows fine on the page, yet when I try to use the datatable search feature the following error appears in debugging. **Element SECHO is undefined in FORM**

**What I think may be wrong.** I think it has something to due with the fact that my new query includes two tables, yet I'm not quite sure how to fix it.

Comment: I'm not seeing a reference to 'secho' in your code. Can you search for the term 'secho' and post that portion of code. This error seems to be common when coldfusion doesn't have the appropriate element in scope.

Comment: Sorry about that, I forgot to add portion of the code.

Comment: First off, using the old comma syntax for a query JOIN is just asking for trouble. Use actual ANSI `JOIN`s instead. Second, this query still looks incredibly vulnerable to injection. Now for your error: My guess is that it has nothing to do with using two table but the fact that `SECHO` isn't getting passed through your form. To troubleshoot, dump out the query that is generated and set to the cfquery. Manually run it. That may give you a more complete error, or at least let you see what kind of query the loop built.

Comment: And if you add a condition before the dynamic part of your `WHERE` (`A.ARCHIVE IS NULL`), you can get rid of `1=1`. `1=1` just ensures that you'll have a valid query >> `....WHERE something <dynamicWhere>`.

Comment: This is looking a little like an XY Problem http://http://xyproblem.info/. What exactly are you trying to use datables to do? Why are you dynamically building a `WHERE` statement with form variables? Will that query change?

Comment: At the very bottom of the tutorial you are following it states: `Watch out for trailing commas after your data elements In your Json. Firefox will compensate for them, but IE thinks there is a missing element so will not display any data at all.` Can you post your JSON response? Or test in firefox?

Comment: What version of datatables are you using? It's possible you're code and version are incongruent. The parameters you're using (`sEcho` amongst others) indicates  you're using datatables legacy code (v1.9).  If you're using v1.10+ then you should downgrade to 1.9.  If you're using 1.10+, you'll need to upgrade your code by referring to the [upgrade guide](https://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10).

Comment: `sEcho` is a legacy parameter that datatables generates automatically on an ajax request.  It expects the server side process to echo the value back in the response. I don't believe this parameter is used or even necessary in 1.10.

Comment: It looks like what I said in not completely acccurate.  Apparently using legacy parameters in 1.10 will force datatables into [compatibility mode](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Legacy).  However, there's still a problem with the ajax request not passing the `sEcho` parameter to the server.  Best I could find was [this](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/25237/idisplaystart-idisplaylength-secho-are-all-null-in-server-side).  So if you're using legacy/compatibility mode, make sure _ALL_ of your parameters are legacy.

Comment: I fixed the query.
'code' SELECT TABLE1.EMPLOYEE_ID, TABLE1.EVER_NUM, TABLE1.LOCATION_ID, TABLE2.LOCATION_NAME
    FROM TABLE1
    RIGHT JOIN
    TABLE2
    ON TABLE1.LOCATION_ID = TABLE2.LOCATION_ID
    WHERE 1 = 1 AND TABLE1.ARCHIVE IS NULL 'code'

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what's causing your error.  It jumped out at me when read your post over again.

> **ORIGINAL WORKING CODE**

```
"fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback ) {
    aoData.push(
        { "name": "table", "value": "ukLocationCodes" },
        { "name": "sql", "value": "SELECT [id], [varCode], [varLocation]" }
        );

        $.ajax( {"dataType": 'json',
             "type": "POST",
             "url": sSource,
             "data": aoData,
             "success": fnCallback} );
```

> **CHANGED CODE, WORKS FINE UNTIL YOU TYPE IN A SEARCH**
>
> In order to lookup more than one table and hide the table and select, I changed the JS script to the following below.

```
$.ajax( {"dataType": 'json',
             "type": "POST",
             "url": sSource,
             "data": aoData,
             "success": fnCallback} );
```

The problem first surfaced when you changed your code from legacy datatables functionality.  Legacy datatables ajax automatically generates and passes the `sEcho` parameter when posting your ajax request.  It also expects the server response to echo the value back in the success callback.

So what happened when you changed your ajax to use your custom ajax call, this bypassed any datatables built-in functionality (i.e. not sending `sEcho`).

To correct the immediate error you have a variety of options.  To correct this properly you probably shouldn't use option 3.

1. Revert your code back to using *ONLY* legacy code and [**legacy parameters**](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/features).  This means your ajax must use `bProcessing`, `bServerSide`, `sAjaxSource` with `fnServerData` as you used originally.
2. Use the **[upgrade guide](https://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10)** and convert legacy datatables to v1.10.
3. This is the easiest but *not recommended*.  Since your custom ajax doesn't post `sEcho`, comment out the reference to `form.sEcho` in your `cfm` file.  This will eliminate the immediate error, but I have no idea what side effects may come out of it.

Comment: More info https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/29141/undefined-secho#Comment_78286

Comment: So it looks like I'm running 1.9+ I was able to use 
processing": true,
"serverSide": true,
"bStateSave": true,
Without error, yet the search still fails on  "sEcho": #form.sEcho#. I'm not really sure what to replace this with?

Comment: Your comment _"it looks like I'm running 1.9"_ is incongruent with `processing": true`, `"serverSide": true` as those parameters didn't exist in 1.9.  I'm 99.9% certain that you're running v1.10+ and mixing 1.9 with 1.10 parameters.  So you need to choose either _ALL_ 1.9 or _ALL_ 1.10 or you'll continue with errors.

Comment: Should you decide you want to revert/stay with legacy, here's a post that should help you replace your updated ajax call back to legacy. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22105762/how-to-use-fnserverdata

Comment: Please pardon my ignorance, I am just trying to figure out why it worked perfectly until I tried to add more than one table in the query. If "sEcho" is the error it would seem like that is where the error occurs and only happend after using  two tables in the query.

Comment: @EddieB no worries, I'm trying to help.  I'm just trying to inform you that you might have come to the wrong conclusion when you thought _"it worked perfectly until I tried to add more than one table in the query"_.  If I read your post correctly, the same time you added a second table to your select, was also the same time you updated the ajax call.  The facts are it doesn't matter to datatables how the result set was derived as long as the server returns valid, expected json.

Comment: `sEcho` only gets sent if you're using 1.9 or using 1.10 in compatibility mode.  It's all in the online docs.  It has nothing to do with the anything related to the query.  I'm trying to help you see that you're barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: Gotcha, I'll try upgrading to the latest version tonight. Thanks again for all the help.

Comment: Great but if I were a gambling man, I'm willing to bet that you're already using v1.10+, so just be certain that you don't mix and match any with any legacy attributes.  I'm currently using 1.10.12 but I didn't need ajax so it was much easier for me than you.  Good luck!

Comment: You were right, I was already on version 1.10. I'll continue try and make the code work with the latest version.

Comment: So, I updated my code using the latest params and now I am getting the following error.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DT_RowId' of undefined
    at Object.rowIdFn

Comment: @EddieB  No worries, I'll check it out later and get back to you later today when I have a chance to look over what you've tried.

Comment: @EddieB  In the meantime, update your post with your most recent code changes.

Comment: Alright, last night I updated the code, to try and get it to work with the latest version of datatable version 1.10. I found saw that I needed to change

** "draw": #form.draw#,
    "recordsTotal": #qGetCount.fullCount#,
    "recordsFiltered": #rResult.recordcount#,**

Now the page give me the following error when the page loads. **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DT_RowId' of undefined** and then when it refreshes, it give an error of **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined**

Comment: @EddieB ok great.  I don't have time right now but I'll check it out later and get back to you.

Comment: If the stack overflow community can get this working, I think it would be a great template for others to use for a ton of other future projects. Thank you @user9263373 for taking the time to look at this.